# ssrs 2008 pie chart performance improvement

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I am querying a single table in my dataset which is relatively small (1.5 million rows). Each row has a column `s_flag`. When i

`select s_flag,count(*) from 'mytable' group by s_flag`

the results return in less than a second.

This is what i want to depict on the pie chart,so i am using this as the equivalent to my query: My dataset is a simple `select * from mytable` .I am adding in the chart's values `count(s_flag)` and in category groups `s_flag`.

The problem is that the chart takes minutes to load. My question is: Is there a way to pass the results from `select s_flag,count(*) from 'mytable' group by s_flag` directly in the chart without using ssrs for the count aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s_flag,count(1) as s_flag_count from 'mytable' group by s_flag
```

Use `s_flag_count` chart's values.